# What does this tweet from Elon Musk mean?

Tags: meaning, sentence

Today I read a [tweet from Elon Musk](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/652643128181026816), in reply to someone else.

One of Musk's previous tweets was discussed in the following AppleInsider article: [Elon Musk walks back Apple Car, Apple Watch aspersions in Twitter confessional](http://ainsdr.co/1WSkYNC)

Elon Musk's reply:

> I didn't walk back anything, apart from media hype.

What does it 'walk back' mean in this context?

Comment: Please give some context. The sentence does not mean much without it. What was the question to which this is the answer? Do you have a link?

Comment: This should get you started http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121350/does-walk-back-have-a-meaning-of-deny-or-keep-distance-from-somebody-some

Comment: This is the initial tweet: Elon Musk walks back Apple Car, Apple Watch aspersions in Twitter confessional  http://ainsdr.co/1WSkYNC  pic.twitter.com/rqDwCd0k2c

Comment: I think this is an OK question. I don't quite understand what it means myself.

Comment: [Here's the Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/walk_back). Looks about right to me.

Answer (score 1):

To *walk back* means to retract, or withdraw, or back-pedal on something you said. So evidently Elon is saying he didn't withdraw his earlier (disparaging) statements on Apple.

Regarding the "media hype": To *walk back media hype* means Musk is going to cut back on media appearances.

So in summary he's saying, **"No, I'm not withdrawing my earlier comments on Apple, but I *am* going to do fewer media appearances/cut my media budget".**

Comment: I think you mean *retract* instead of *detract*.

Comment: And apart from media hype? How it will sound in normal English all together?

Comment: It means he's going to cut back on media appearances ("media hype"). It's sort of a play on words. He's saying, "No, I'm not withdrawing my earlier comments, but I *am* going to cut back on media appearances." See this link: http://electrek.co/2015/10/13/tesla-ceo-elon-musk-goes-on-two-different-shows-to-say-he-will-cut-back-on-media/

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.